# upgrade custom chain to 0.9.24, rpc-client/src/main.rs report "no `AuthorClient` in `author`"

Tags: rpc, upgrade

report "no `AuthorClient` in `author`" in rpc-client/src/main.rs when i upgrade chain to 0.9.24

report "add `dyn` keyword before this trait" if i change to AuthorApiClient.

does AuthorApiClient and AuthorClient not work?

```
cargo check
   Compiling node-runtime v2.0.1 (/Users/li/Documents/GitHub/deeper-chain/runtime)
    Checking node-rpc-client v2.0.0 (/Users/li/Documents/GitHub/deeper-chain/rpc-client)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `sc_rpc_api::author::AuthorClient`
  --> rpc-client/src/main.rs:28:49
   |
28 | use sc_rpc_api::author::{hash::ExtrinsicOrHash, AuthorClient};
   |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                                                 |
   |                                                 no `AuthorClient` in `author`
   |                                                 help: a similar name exists in the module: `AuthorApiClient`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `node-rpc-client` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

rpc-client/src/main.rs

```
// This file is part of Substrate.

// Copyright (C) 2019-2021 Parity Technologies (UK) Ltd.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

#![warn(missing_docs)]

//! Example substrate RPC client code.
//!
//! This module shows how you can write a Rust RPC client that connects to a running
//! substrate node and use statically typed RPC wrappers.

use futures::{Future, TryFutureExt};
use jsonrpc_core_client::{transports::http, RpcError};
use node_primitives::Hash;
use sc_rpc_api::author::{hash::ExtrinsicOrHash, AuthorApiClient};

fn main() -> Result<(), RpcError> {
    sp_tracing::try_init_simple();

    futures::executor::block_on(async {
        let uri = "http://localhost:9933";

        http::connect(uri)
            .and_then(|client: AuthorApiClient<Hash, Hash>| remove_all_extrinsics(client))
            .await
    })
}

/// Remove all pending extrinsics from the node.
///
/// The example code takes `AuthorApiClient` and first:
/// 1. Calls the `pending_extrinsics` method to get all extrinsics in the pool.
/// 2. Then calls `remove_extrinsic` passing the obtained raw extrinsics.
///
/// As the result of running the code the entire content of the transaction pool is going
/// to be removed and the extrinsics are going to be temporarily banned.
fn remove_all_extrinsics(
    client: AuthorApiClient<Hash, Hash>,
) -> impl Future<Output = Result<(), RpcError>> {
    client
        .pending_extrinsics()
        .and_then(move |pending| {
            client.remove_extrinsic(
                pending
                    .into_iter()
                    .map(|tx| ExtrinsicOrHash::Extrinsic(tx.into()))
                    .collect(),
            )
        })
        .map_ok(|removed| {
            println!("Removed extrinsics: {:?}", removed);
        })
}
```